# Summarize Excel Cells In PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, cell

I want to summarize number of cells from a sheet in excel into an array cell. Unfortunately it saves the numbers in the cells as strings and not as the actual sum. Tired to change the cell type to "value" but it seems to be not working.

How shall I get the value from the cell as "double" type?

```
$EntryAmmount[25] = $IncomingSummary1Worksheet.Cells.Item(69,18).Text + $IncomingSummary1Worksheet.Cells.Item(71,18).Text
```

In this situation it throws this error (0.00 and 29,453.17 are the values in the cells):

```
Cannot convert value "0.0029,453.17" to type "System.Double". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:...PS.ps1:148 char:5
+     $EntryAmmount[25] = $IncomingSummary1Worksheet.Cells.Item(69, ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToDoubleOrSingle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the values to double, in your current code the op_addition (`+`) method is acting on string types and is therefore concatenating them.

Try:

```
$EntryAmmount[25] = [double]$IncomingSummary1Worksheet.Cells.Item(69,18).Text + [double]$IncomingSummary1Worksheet.Cells.Item(71,18).Text
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you solve the problem